# How To Send Email Using MailKit With VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp, mailkit

I'm trying to send an email using MailKit and VB.net code.

The email is sending except the body of the email message is always blank.

Here is my code. I suspect the problem is with this line:

```
message.Body = New TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) With {
      .Text = "Test Message"
    }
```

I converted the code from C# to VB.net and don't know if this is the correct syntax in VB.net to set the Text property?

```
    'Create email message
    Dim email As MimeMessage = New MimeMessage()
    email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(MyFromEmail))
    email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(MyToEmail))
    email.Subject = "Test Email Subject"

    Dim message As MimeMessage = New MimeMessage()
    message.Body = New TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) With {
      .Text = "Test Message"
    }

    'Send email
    Dim smtp As MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient = New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()

    smtp.Connect(MySmtpServer, MySmtpServerPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect)
    smtp.Authenticate(MySendingEmail, MySendingPassword)
    smtp.Send(email)
    smtp.Disconnect(True)
```

Comment: _(Disclaimer: I haven't used MailKit yet)_. You create 2 `MimeMessage` objects (email, message). You add the body to the 2nd one (message), but you actually send the 1st one (email) in `smtp.Send(email)`. Creating the 2nd object seems unnecessary. Simply doing `email.Body = New TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) With { .Text = "Test Message" }` should IMHO do the trick.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. 

```email.Body = New TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) With { .Text = "Test Message" }```

worked!

Answer (score 1):

For settings the body I would use the BodyBuilder class:

```
 Dim objBodyBuilder As New BodyBuilder
 objBodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<b>HTML message</b>"
 objBodyBuilder.TextBody = "Plain text"
 objBodyBuilder.Attachments.Add("an attachment")
 message.Body = objBodyBuilder.ToMessageBody()
```